# Confusion about difference between Normal and Perfectly Normal

Tags: general-topology, definition

I am working with the following definitions:

> A topological space is normal if and only if every pair
>   of disjoint, nonempty closed sets can be separated by a continuous function.
>
> A topological space is called perfectly normal if whenever C and D are disjoint, nonempty, closed subsets of X, there exists a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow [0,1]$ s.t $C = f^{-1}(0)$ and $D = f^{-1}(1)$

I can't see why perfectly normal is stronger than normality, from these definitions they seem equivalent to me.

Comment: But then why is perfectly normal a stronger property ?

Comment: Why do they seem equivalent?

Comment: Your definition of perfectly normal is incorrect.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4276135/52912.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I lied when I said the two definitions were equivalent; I was overlooking something.

Say $A$ and $B$ can be "separated by a continuous function" if there exists $f$ so that $f=0$ on $A$ and $f=1$ on $B$. Then it's true that a space is normal if and only if any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by a continuous function.

Saying $A$ and $B$ are separated by $f$ says that $A\subset f^{-1}(0)$ and $B\subset f^{-1}(1)$. The definition of "perfectly normal" says $A= f^{-1}(0)$ and $B= f^{-1}(1)$, a stronger condition (people sometimes say that $A$ and $B$ are "precisely separated" by $f$).

It's not hard to show from Urysohn's Lemma that a space is perfectly normal if and only if it is normal *and* every closed set is a $G_\delta$.

Comment: If $f:X\to [0,1]$ is continuous and $A=f^{-1}\{0\}$ then $A=\cap_{n\in N}f^{-1}[0,1/n)$ is $G_{\delta}$ in $X.$

Comment: @user254665 That's the trivial direction. Now suppose $A$ is a closed $G_\delta$ and show there exists $f$ with $A=f^{-1}(0)$.