# Perfectly Normal is hereditary

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

The definitions I'm working with:

> $(X, T )$ is called perfectly normal if whenever $C$ and $D$ are disjoint, nonempty, closed subsets of $X$, there exists a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow [0, 1]$ s.t $C = f^{−1}(\{0\})$ and $D = f^{−1}(\{1\})$.
>
> A topological space is normal if and only if every pair
> of disjoint, nonempty closed sets can be separated by a continuous function

In particular the definition of normal doesn't assume $T_1$. I can prove that every perfectly normal space is normal, but since normal is not hereditary I don't see how that helps. My problem is that any two disjoint closed sets in a subspace are not necessarily disjoint in X.
I have also tried working with the alternative definition of perfectly normal, i.e a space is perfectly normal iff it is normal and every closed subset is $G_{\delta}$, but I run into the same problem namely that the closed disjoint sets of the subspace are not necessarily disjoint in X. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. First show that if $F$ is a relatively closed subset of $Y$, there is a continuous $f:Y\to[0,1]$ such that $F=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$. Then let $F$ and $G$ be disjoint relatively closed subsets of $Y$. By the first result there are continuous $f,g:Y\to[0,1]$ such that $F=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $G=g^{-1}[\{0\}]$. Consider the function

$$h:Y\to[0,1]:y\mapsto\frac{f(y)}{f(y)+g(y)}\;.$$

Comment: Great hint, thank you ! I have one question though, doesn't this show that $ F \subseteq h^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and similarly $G  \subseteq h^{-1}[\{1\}]$ and that shows that Y is normal, but how do we show it is perfectly normal

Comment: @jia: $h(y)=0$ if and only if $f(y)=0$ if and only if $y\in F$, and $h(y)=1$ if and only if $f(y)=f(y)+g(y)$ if and only if $g(y)=0$ if and only if $y\in G$, so $F=h^{-1}[\{0\}$, and $G=h^{-1}[\{1\}]$. (Even if that weren’t the case, the property that closed sets are $G_\delta$ is hereditary and to gether with normality implies perfect normality.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Please checks my try from your hint.

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a perfectly normal space $X$.
Let $F$ and $G$ be disjoint closed sets in $Y$.
Then $F = Y \cap F'$ and $G = Y \cap G'$ for some closed sets $F'$ and $G'$ in X.
Since $X$ is perfectly normal, there exist a continuous function $f' : X \to [0,1]$ and $g' : X \to [0,1]$ such that $F' = f'^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$ and $G' = g'^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$...

How can I show that the sets $F'$ and $G'$ are disjoint?

Thank you.

Comment: @nameless: You can’t: they may not be disjoint. You should follow the hint instead. You *can* show that there are a continuous $f_0:X\to[0,1]$ such that $F'=f_0^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and a continuous $g_0:X\to[0,1]$ such that $G'=g_0^{-1}[\{0\}]$. Let $f$ and $g$ be the restrictions of $f_0$ and $g_0$ to $Y$, and build $h$ as in the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your definition of perfectly normal

> $(X, T )$ is called *perfectly normal* if whenever $C$ and $D$ are disjoint, **nonempty**, closed subsets of $X$, there exists a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow [0, 1]$ s.t $C = f^{−1}(\{0\})$ and $D = f^{−1}(\{1\})$.

is incorrect.  You need to remove the "nonempty" from there.

The condition must be satisfied for all disjoint closed sets $C$ and $D$, even if one of them is empty.  If one of them is empty, say $D$, the condition says that each closed set $C$ must be the zero set of some real valued function (which implies each closed set is a $G_\delta$).

If you keep the nonempty in the definition, that will not be the case: each [ultraconnected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraconnected_space) would trivially be perfectly normal, for the trivial reason that there are no disjoint nonempty closed subsets; but that is not true.  For example in the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) $X=\{0,1\}$ with $1$ as the only open point, the singleton $\{0\}$ is closed, but is not a $G_\delta$.