# About perfectly normal spaces.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In some books the terms: regular and $T_3$; normal and $T_4$; completely normal and $T_5$; perfectly normal and $T_6$ are synonyms, but in some books, the difference is that regular, normal, completely regular and perfectly regular spaces are not $T_1$ and $T_3, T_4, T_5, T_6$ spaces are $T_1$.

If we take the second definitions (that regular and $T_3$ and other pairs are *not* synonymous), than $T_6 \implies T_5 \implies T_4\implies T_3$, but completely normal $\implies$ normal but normal spaces do not include regular spaces. I know that perfectly normal $\implies$ completely normal.

But I am interested in: Does there exist

1. A perfectly normal space that is $T_0$ but not $T_1$.
2. A perfectly normal space that is not $T_0$ and is not regular.
3. A perfectly normal space that is not $T_0$, is regular but is not completely regular.
4. A perfectly normal space that is not $T_0$ and is completely regular.

Comment: How do you define perfectly normal and completely normal? In the without the $T_1$ version.

Comment: maybe: perfectly normal: every pair of disjoint closed sets $F$ and $G$ can be exactly separated by a continuous $f: X \to [0,1]$ (so that $f^{-1}[\{0\}]=F$ and $f^{-1}[\{1\}]=G$). and completely normal: every subspace is normal (in the sense that (relatively) closed disjoint subsets can be separated by (relatively) open sets)?

Comment: And in your definitions how does one show perf. normal implies completely normal? In my suggested ones this is not quite clear, I think.

Comment: I misread the title as "Almost perfectly normal spaces", and thought it was about some unheard-of new refinement of the hierarchy of separation axioms. I expect it'll actually happen sometime. :)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma :  The reason that a perfectly normal space must be completely normal is in two steps: (1) any subspace of a perfectly normal space is perfectly normal (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840614/perfectly-normal-is-hereditary for this); (2) any perfectly normal space is normal (I think that you're OK with this).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the definitions in my comment: if $X$ is perfectly normal and $T_0$ then let $x \in X$, and suppose it were not closed, so we have $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$ with $y \neq x$. Then $T_0$ tells us we have an open $U$ containing $x$ but not containing $y$ (the other way around is ruled out in this situation). Apply perfect normality and we get a continuous $f: X \to [0,1]$ that $f^{-1}[\{0\}]=U^\complement$, so in particular $f(y)=0$ and $f(x)=p > 0$. But then $f^{-1}[[0,p)]$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ missing $\{x\}$, contradiction. So $\{x\}$ must be closed and so $X$ is $T_1$ (and hence $T_2$, etc.). So then a space as in 1. does not exist.

The indiscrete space on $\{0,1\}$ is not $T_0$ but *is* perfectly normal: it is normal for trivial reasons (no non-trivial disjoint closed sets to consider) and it is a [$G_\delta$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_space). This is an example for 2, and possibly for 4.?

Comment: An indiscrete space is regular, and indeed completely regular, using the non-$\mathrm T_1$ versions of these terms, so a nontrivial indiscrete space is an example of (4) but not (2). (I think that you may have misread (2), since the cases are written so that they must be mutually exclusive, so nothing could be an example for both (2) and (4).)

Answer (score 1):

There are no examples for (2) and (3), for essentially the same reason that (as proved in Henno's answer) there are no examples for (1).  A perfectly normal space must be $ \mathrm R _ 0 $ (which is a non-$ \mathrm T _ 0 $ version of $ \mathrm T _ 1 $), and Henno's answer is just the $ \mathrm T _ 0 $ version of the proof of that; a direct proof can be found at the self-answered question [Perfectly normal spaces are completely regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525139/perfectly-normal-spaces-are-completely-regular) by @PatrickR (which is what brought this to my attention).  And it's well-known that an $ \mathrm R _ 0 $ normal space must be completely regular (by an argument that's also pretty much contained in Henno's answer).

On the other hand, Henno's answer already has an example of (4): any nontrivial indiscrete space.