# Perfectly normal spaces are completely regular

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, separation-axioms

First some definitions:

> A space $X$ is called [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space) if points and closed sets can be separated by functions (if $x\notin F$ with $F$ closed, there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f[F]=\{0\}$ and $f(x)=1$). (Hausdorff not assumed here.)
>
> A space $X$ is called [perfectly normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) if disjoint closed sets can be precisely separated by functions (if $E$ and $F$ are disjoint closed sets, there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=E$ and $f^{-1}(1)=F$). Equivalently (Vedenissoff's theorem), every closed set is a zero-set (= the set of zeros of some real valued continuous function). (Again, Hausdorff not assumed here.)

I can't find a reference for the following result anywhere:

> **Proposition:** Every perfectly normal space is completely regular.

Note that the assumption cannot be weakened to normal spaces, or even to completely normal spaces.  For example, the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_space) is completely normal, but is not completely regular.  It's not even regular.

I have provided a proof below; let me know if there is a problem or if you can find a reference.

Answer (score 2):

*Proof:* Suppose $X$ is perfectly normal. Let $F$ be a closed set and $x$ a point not in $F$.  By perfect normality, $F$ is the zero set of some continous $f:X\to[0,1]$.  As $x\notin F$, we have $f(x)\ne 0$.  It is then a simple matter to tweak $f$ to get $f(x)=1$.

---

For reference, this also follows from a more general result:

> **Proposition:** Every space that is $R_0$ and normal is completely regular.

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990826) for a proof.

Here, an [$R_0$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) is a space whose Kolmogorov quotient is $T_1$.  There are many equivalent characterizations (see wikipedia for details).  One of them is that for a closed set $F$ and a point $x\notin F$, we have $F\cap\operatorname{cl}\{x\}=\emptyset$.  A perfectly normal space has this property by an argument similar to the first proof above.

Comment: I don't know why the usual references don't have this, but this seems undeniably correct.

Comment: It looks like your proof is essentially already in the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3467496/ (although this one assumes $\mathrm T_0$ and so is a little obscured by that).